# Extract a specific line from a SELECT statement based on the last Trasanction date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Good day,

I have an SQL code that return to me all quantities that I received over time, but I want to display only the latest one

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT DISTINCT
        [dbo].[ttcibd001110].[t_cmnf] AS [Manufacturer],
        [dbo].[ttcibd001110].[t_item] AS [Item code],
        [dbo].[ttcibd001110].[t_dsca] AS [Description],
        [dbo].[ttcibd001110].[t_seak] AS [Search key 1],
        [dbo].[twhinr110110].[t_trdt] AS [Transaction date],
        [dbo].[twhinr110110].[t_cwar] AS [Warehouse],
        [dbo].[twhinr110110].[t_qstk] AS [Quantity Inventory Unit]

        FROM [dbo].[twhinr110110] LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ttcibd001110]
            ON [dbo].[twhinr110110].[t_item]=[dbo].[ttcibd001110].[t_item]
            WHERE [dbo].[twhinr110110].[t_koor]='2' AND [dbo].[ttcibd001110].[t_cmnf]='ManufacturerX') AS tabel 
WHERE ltrim(tabel.[Item code])='1000045'
```

Now, from this selection I want to select only the line with the latest Transaction date, but I am stuck.

Can somebody help me in this way?

Thank you!

Comment: Above the code that I put it here I have also the line with USE db...thank you

Comment: Sorry...is SQL Server...I am beginner in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your beginning to

```
SELECT TOP 1
```

and after where use

```
ORDER BY [Transaction date] DESC
```

Comment: Specify column alias in ORDER BY clause?